# Python async proxy status check

Tags: python, asynchronous

Good day, im trying to master async stuff in python and have stuck in a situation which should be easily solvable, but i`m still frustrated what am i doing wrong. Suggest i have a list of proxies and i want to check if servers are up and running, and what is more important i want to do it in async way, unfortunately comparison with sync function shows the same time of execution.

So, to the code:

```
import requests
import os
import asyncio

from lxml import html


class GetUkProxy:
    url = "https://free-proxy-list.net/uk-proxy.html"

    def __init__(self):
        self.getProxyList(self.url)

    def getProxyList(self, url):
        self.proxies = []
        data = requests.get(url)
        response = html.fromstring(data.text)
        for item in response.xpath('//table[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr'):
            ip, port = item.getchildren()[:2]
            self.proxies.append({'IP': ip.text, 'Port': port.text, 'Status': 'unknown'})

    def printProxies(self):
        try:
            for proxy in self.proxies:
                print(proxy['IP'] + ':' + proxy['Port'], proxy['Status'])
        except:
            print("Proxy list is empty")

    def checkProxies(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = loop.run_until_complete(self.checkProxyList())
        loop.close()


    async def checkProxyList(self):
        try:
            tasks = []
            for proxy in self.proxies[:10]:
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.checkProxy(proxy))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        except:
            print('Proxy list is empty')

    async def checkProxy(self, proxy=None):
        try:
            check = os.system('ping -n 4 -w 2 ' + proxy['IP'])
            if not check:
                proxy['Status'] = 'Dead'
            else:
                proxy['Status'] = 'Alive'
        except Exception as exp:
            print(exp)

    def syncCheck(self):
        for item in self.proxies[:10]:
            check = os.system('ping -n 4 -w 2 ' + item['IP'])
```

time of execution of async checkProxies is equal to the time of execution of synchronous syncCheck, so any ideas what is the root of the mistake and how to fix it are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` is a synchronous function that blocks the event loop.

You can execute system commands asynchronously using `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` and keep from blocking the event loop.

```
async def checkProxy(self, proxy=None):
    try:
        check = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'ping', '-c', '4', '-W', '2', proxy['IP'], stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
        out, error = await check.communicate()

        proxy['Status'] = 'Alive'

        if error:
            proxy['Status'] = 'Dead'
    except Exception as exp:
        print(exp)
```

**Edit:** In `checkProxies` method we'll make a list of futures to be run together.

```
def checkProxies(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    proxies = self.proxies[:10]
    tasks = [self.checkProxy(proxy) for proxy in proxies]


    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(
            *tasks
        )
    )

    loop.close()

uk = GetUkProxy()
uk.checkProxies()
print(uk.proxies)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that saved my day! Offtop: could u suggest some book/article/tutorial to study asyncio stuff like u demonstrated in your answer?

Comment: Hmm, there is a problem - although it`s performing fast, seems that out and error and never filled - proxy status after execution remains 'unknown'. Could you pls look at your code once more.

Comment: That's because we're using a copy of `self.proxies` when slicing `self.proxies[:10]`. For reference, you can see [`vanheem` slide here](https://github.com/vangheem/asyncio-presentation/tree/master) and [examples in ProgrammerCreek](https://www.programcreek.com/python/index/5526/asyncio)

Comment: Apparantly, there seems to be something else, if i add print(out, error) after line with check.communication it prints nothing, or i understand something improperly?

Comment: I was wrong about using a copy when slicing. I'll share what changes for `checkProxies`

Comment: Sorry mate, but your code isn`t working for me - still it prints nothing. Did you tested it by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did. Copy and tryout the code in this [Repl](https://repl.it/KkfT/1)